# How to prevent with mapbox gl js, that a mouse wheel interaction stops a fitBounds() animation?

Tags: javascript, animation, scroll, mapbox-gl-js, fitbounds

I add some marker to a mapbox map and let the fitBounds() method from geojson-extent.js adjust the map position and zoom.

```
map.fitBounds( geojsonExtent(geojson), {
    padding: {top: 200, bottom:30, left: 30, right: 30}
});
```

The animation duration is set by default to five seconds. When the user do a mouse wheel interaction in this time over the map, the animation stops. No problem: The zoom stops the animation. But how can I prevent this?

I tried a lot of solutions:

**1. disable the zoom**

```
map['scrollZoom'].disable();
```

User can't scroll the map by mouse wheel, but animation still stops.

**2. catch the wheel event**

```
map.on('wheel', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

User can't scroll the map by mouse wheel, but animation still stops.

**3. disable user interaction completely**

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    interactive: false
});
```

Cool, animation is not being interrupted any more, but now the user can't pan the map. I found no solution to reset this property on run time or add navigation elements for panning.

**4. set animation to important**

```
map.fitBounds( geojsonExtent(geojson), {
    essential: true,
    padding: {top: 200, bottom:30, left: 30, right: 30}
});
```

No effect.

**5. disable animation**

```
map.fitBounds( geojsonExtent(geojson), {
    animate: false,
    padding: {top: 200, bottom:30, left: 30, right: 30}
});
```

This works, but it's a kind of workaround. I like to keep the animation.

**6. add an overlay to block the user interaction**

```
map.on('movestart', function(e){
    $("#map-box").append('<div class="block-interactions"></div>');
});
map.on('moveend', function(e){
    $("#map-box .block-interactions").remove();
});
```

```
.block-interactions {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 535px; /* map height */
}
```

This is my current solution and it works, but feels like a bad hack and is still a workaround.

So, do you have an other idea to prevent the animation being interrupted?
At best with mapbox methods.

Thank you, for your help!

Comment: Seems to be a bug: 

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/9230#issuecomment-578190020

Answer (score 1):

You can disable interaction before calling `fitBounds` and then re-enable it in response to `moveend` and `zoomend` events.

```
// define map here...

function disableInteraction() {
    map.scrollZoom.disable()
}

function enableInteraction() {
    map.scrollZoom.enable()
}

map.on('moveend', function() {
    enableInteraction()
})

map.on('zoomend', function() {
    enableInteraction()
})

// The next two lines should go wherever you want to invoke `fitBounds`
disableInteraction()
map.fitBounds(/* ... */)
```

You can modify `disableInteraction` and `enableInteraction` if you want to disable other forms of interaction besides scroll zoom. For example, to disable everything:

```
function disableInteraction() {
    map.scrollZoom.disable()
    map.boxZoom.enable()
    map.dragRotate.enable()
    map.dragPan.enable()
    map.keyboard.enable()
    map.doubleClickZoom.enable()
    map.touchZoomRotate.enable()
}
```